# How to add katakana to SQLite3?

Tags: sqlite, utf-16, utf-32

I looking to write katakana into a SQLite3 database, I understand that SQLite3 uses UTF-16 and was wondering if there is any way to incorporate the UTF-32bit character set. If there isn't a way then can someone suggest how to input katakana in to a SQLite data base as text.

Comment: Why would you need 32 bits for katakana?

Comment: katakana isn't available for UTF32. I'm sure of it.

Comment: No matter how sure you are, you're wrong. Katakana [ア](https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/U+30A2) has a UTF16 encoding of `0x30A2` and a UTF32 encoding of `0x000030A2` . The UTF32 encoding for all katakana idioms is the two bytes of the UTF16 encoding preceded by two null bytes.

Comment: ok but SQLite still wont read the katakana characters that is what I am asking help with how to save katakana in a SQLite database.

Comment: Sqlite stores text as Unicode. The default is UTF-8, but when first creating a database that can be changed to UTF-16 with a pragma. The C API has functions for binding UTF-8 and UTF-16 encoded strings to parameters and the internals will translate appropriately. So you just have to go to from UTF-32 to whichever other one is easier in the programming language you're using. This is usually transparent or nearly so in most language bindings to the Sqlite API.